# Laravel get pivot from two model instances

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am attempting to get pivot information in a view (using blade). I have passed the two model instances that are connected via a pivot into the view. So the available variables are:

`$recipe` `$ingredient`

I am aware that you can get pivot information from a model instance using a foreach loop:

```
@foreach ($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
    <h1>{{$ingredient->pivot->amount}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

(Docs for the above code: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)

But I would like to do it with the available variables. If anyone knows how to do this that would be pretty epic.

Comment: `$recipe->$ingredients` Is that a typo ? Because it should be like `$recipe->ingredients` and I don't think you need to pass `$ingredients` into the blade.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, thanks for that. Yeah you don't need to pass in the $ingredients variable. But the question is posed for a situation where it's provided. Like If you were looking at a recipe (view) and on that view you can see the ingredients. If you were to select an ingredient (that sends you to a view which passes in the recipe and the ingredient) this would present a view that shows pivot informaiton with the two provided variables.

Comment: Sorry, am not fully understanding what you're trying to achieve what you mean by when you say "do it with the avalible variables"

Comment: So the available variables are `$recipe` and `$ingredient`. How would you get the pivot connecting the two variables.